# cmath asin() problems

Tags: c++, cmath

Hey so i managed to locate the problem in some graphics math i am coding, and apparently when i reach this line of code: `float test3= asin(test2);` where `test2= 0.017409846`.

to my understanding 'asin' is 'arc sin' which is 'inverse sin' (what i want) the result of this line of code however is `test3 = 0.017410725`. when plugging this into my calculator inverse sine of test2 is .997561.

**Why isn't `asin` working?? thanks!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calculator is set to *degrees* mode. The `asin()` function returns *radians*.

Degrees and radians are related by the formula:

degrees = (180/π) * radians

Answer (score 1):

It is working, you're using wrong units. `asin` takes radians, and your calculator is probably in degrees mode.

Answer (score 1):

arcsine return value is expressed in radians, not in degrees (your calculator is probably set to display degrees).